# Update multiple SQL records with single query MySQL query with npm mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

Thanks for taking a look at this!  I am attempting to update a few records in MySQL with a single query; however, I am using a class with Promises to create a group of synchronis queries and I cannot seem to get this to work.  Here is what I currently have:

req.body is an array of objects with two key/value pairs...

API:

```
router.post('/verified', (req, res) => {
    let database = new Database(dbOptions);
    let verifiedItemsArray = [];
    let sqlQueryArray = [];

    let updateQuery = 'UPDATE `raw_unverified` SET `funding_source` = ? WHERE `ritm_number` = ?';
    let verifiedItemArray = [req.body[0].funding_source, req.body[0].ritm_number];

    database.beginTransaction([updateQuery], verifiedItemArray)
        .then(response => console.log(response))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));

    res.send('Update Successful');
});
```

database class:

```
class Database {
    constructor(config) {
        this.connection = mysql.createConnection(config);
    }

    query(sqlQuery, sqlArgs) {
        console.log(sqlQuery);
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
            this.connection.query(sqlQuery, ((sqlArgs) ? [sqlArgs] : null), (error, results) => {

                if (error) return reject(error);
                resolve(results);
            });
        });
    }

    beginTransaction(sqlQueries, sqlArgs) {
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {
            let allResults = [];
            this.connection.beginTransaction( (error) => {
                if (error) return reject(error);

                for (let i = 0; i < sqlQueries.length; i++) {
                    this.query(sqlQueries[i], ((sqlArgs) ? sqlArgs[i] : null))
                        .then((results) => {
                            allResults.push(results);
                        })
                        .catch((error) => {
                            throw error;
                        });
                }

                this.connection.commit( (error) => {
                    if (error) return reject(error);
                    resolve(allResults);
                });
            });
        });
    }
}

module.exports = Database;
```

And here is the error that I get:

> UPDATE `raw_unverified` SET `funding_source` = ? WHERE `ritm_number` = ?
>
> (node:8216) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1

Any help will be much appreciated and anything that I could do better, please feel free to point out!

Thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: Seems like your parameters are not being passed to the query

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking; however, I am not sure on how to correct.  I am using the same syntax (without multiple parameters) elsewhere without issue..  I do suspect that is my problem though

Comment: It seems as though that the parameters are both being interpolated at the ending ?.  Is this syntax with multiple ?'s for interpolation of multiple parameters incorrect?

Comment: Sorry, mispoke - meant to say both parameters are being interpolated as the first ?...

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
this.query(sqlQueries[i], ((sqlArgs) ? sqlArgs[i] : null))
```

you're passing arguments to queries by index - that means you need to change

```
database.beginTransaction([updateQuery], verifiedItemArray)
```

to

```
database.beginTransaction([updateQuery], [verifiedItemArray])
```

Comment: I have tried that and it appears as though it is ignoring interpolation for one of the parameters.  Here is the error I get when I make the above change:

UPDATE `raw_unverified` SET `funding_source` = ? WHERE `ritm_number` = ?
(node:24124) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''RITM0023492' WHERE `ritm_number` = ?' at line 1